# Extract subsidence data from MODFLOW-2000 binary output using FloPy

Tags: python, flopy

I am using MODFLOW-2000 to run a land subsidence model. However, the output of the subsidence file is in binary data. Is there any way to use the python script to convert it into text since I am doing hundreds of scenarios for the model.

Comment: Flagged, either give more details (if your problem is unique or your solution doesn't work) or search Stack Overflow yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary output from the SUB package has the same format as MODFLOW binary head files. You need to know the name of the output text string written to the binary file. See Table 1 in the [MODFLOW-2005 online documentation](https://water.usgs.gov/ogw/modflow/MODFLOW-2005-Guide/) for the SUB package to determine the text string for a given SUB package binary file.

The following shows how to convert `Z DISPLACEMENT` data in a binary subsidence file to an ascii file using `flopy` and `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
import flopy

# open the binary file
sobj = flopy.utils.HeadFile('model.zdisplacement.bin', 
                            text='Z DISPLACEMENT')

# get all of the available times in the file
times = sobj.get_times()

# extract the data for the last time in the file
zd = sobj.get_data(totim=times[-1])

# save the z-displacement for the first layer (layer 0) to an ascii file
# zd is a 3D numpy array with a shape of (nlay, nrow, ncol)
np.savetxt('layer0.zdisplacement.txt', zd[0])
```

If you have more than one layer you will need to save the data for each layer.

You could output all of the data in the file using:

```
for t in sobj.get_times():
    zd = sobj.get_data(totim=t)
    for k in range(nlay):
        fpth = 'layer{}_{}.zdisplacement.txt'.format(k, t)
        np.savetxt(fpth, zd[k])
```

Comment: Thanks, Dr. Hughes. However, how to print out all the time step and stress period? I tried to use the  sobj.get_alldata(), but it shows that "Expected 1D or 2D array, got %dD array instead" % X.ndim)
ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 3D array instead

Comment: @Z.Cao A possible solution has been added to the answer above.

Comment: Thank you so much!